# Microsoft Fabric-Delta parquet format?

Tags: parquet, delta-lake, microsoft-fabric

I started learning Microsoft fabric. As per Microsoft document data's are stored in Delta-Parquet format. I searched over internet I found both are different file fomats (delta format /parquet format).But here they  mentioned delta-parquet fomat.

I want to know both file formats are merged and called it as delta-parquet format? or any other ?

Answer (score 2):

The use of 'Delta' and 'Delta-parquet' are interchangeable. Most people have now dropped the '-parquet' and just refer to these objects as 'Delta'

It can be confusing. Delta are parquet files, with an extra bit of metadata, so so the compute workload you put on the file store, can do transactional workloads like Update, Merge and Delete, and retain versions and other stuff, which you can't do (at least easily) with regular parquet files.

Delta is supported in Databricks, Spark and the Fabric service.

Delta Lake is open source full detail can be found here https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-faq.html